# Is it compact in product topology?

Tags: general-topology

> Define $A_n=\{0,1\}$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ and suppose it is given discrete topology, then will $\prod^{\infty}_{n=1} A_n$ with product topology be compact?

Since $A_n$ is compact, by Tychonoff's theorem the product will be compact. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Tychonoff's theorem

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Being finite, $A_n$ is compact, since for all subsets of $A_n$ each of its open covers is finite (and thus it is its own finite subcover).

Tychonoff's theorem assures compactness of arbitrary products of compact spaces, therefore also $\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$ is compact.

Comment: Good. However, since Tychonoff's theorem depends on the axiom of choice, one may wish to give a direct proof for the space $\prod_{n-1}^\infty A_n$ by showing that it is homeomorphic to the Cantor set, a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Nice remark! I prefered to keep it simple for OP

Comment: Discrete is superfluous. Finite is enough for compactness.

Comment: True. Editing that